# Multiple entries with the same reference in a table with SQL

Tags: sql, multiple-columns

In a unique table, I have multiple lines with the same reference information (`ID`). For the same `day`, customers had `drink` and the `Appreciation` is either 1 (yes) or 0 (no).

```
Table 
ID   DAY Drink   Appreciation
1    1   Coffee   1
1    1   Tea      0
1    1   Soda     1
2    1   Coffee   1
2    1   Tea      1
3    1   Coffee   0
3    1   Tea      0
3    1   Iced Tea 1
```

I first tried to see who appreciated a certain drink, which is obviously very simple

```
Select ID, max(appreciation)
from table 
where (day=1 and drink='coffee' and appreciation=1) 
or (day=1 and drink='tea' and appreciation=1)
```

Since I am not even interested in the drink, I used `max` to remove duplicates and keep only the lane with the highest appreciation.

But what I want to do now is to see who in fact appreciated every drink they had. Again, I am not interested in every lane in the end, but only the ID and the appreciation. How can I modify my `where` to have it done on every single ID? Adding the ID in the condition is also not and option. I tried switching `or` for `and`, but it doesn't return any value. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT ID
FROM table
WHERE DRINK IN ('coffee','tea') -- or whatever else filter you want.
group by ID
HAVING MIN(appreciation) > 0
```

What it does is:
It looks for the minimum appreciation and see to it that that is bigger than 0 for all lines in the group. And the group is the ID, as defined in the group by clause.

as you can see i'm using the having clause, because you can't have aggregate functions in the where section.

Of course you can join other tables into the query as you like. Just be carefull not to add some unwanted filter by joining, which might reduce your dataset in this query.

Comment: It seems to work when I don't need to specify which `drink` I am interested in, but what if I want the info for specific ones, like both coffee and tea, or tea and soda? ( The last one is just an example, it isn't in the table) Also, I assume that I can join tables just as in a regular query?

Comment: add the drink to the where clause. If you want to query for multiple drinks use the IN operator, for example: WHERE drink IN ('coffee','tea').

Comment: I've added an example filter.